# Searching for a specific book about a woman born on the edge of the veil between worlds

Tags: story-identification, female-characters

I found this book in a library and want to see if it has a sequel. The main character is a woman who was born on the edge of a magical wasteland on a special day where the magical world and her world touch and has magic powers resulting from being born on the edge of the two worlds. This manifests as she grows with the weather reflecting her moods and *incidents* around her little village. Everything changes one day when a warrior arrives on his very ugly warhorse. The warrior turns out to be on a quest to find the female main character and his "horse" is actually some kind of carnivorous creature. He teaches her a bit of control over her magic. The final conflict involves the main character going to the magical world and resolving it with her powers.

Comment: When did you read this?  Note that if you borrowed the book, it may be possible to ask the library to review your borrowing history.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't check it out I read the whole thing right there on the aisle floor, a habit that I am trying to break for this exact reason . It was 2 years ago

Comment: It's still worth asking the librarian. They often have a good idea about the books on their shelves...

Comment: Unfortunately I live in a state where the libraries are so understaffed that they told me they didn't have time to help me with it over the phone (I now live too far away to just go look myself). It doesn't help that in that library's system there is no separate fantasy genre, all the fantasy is lumped under sci-fi.